# make vs $(MAKE) for submakes in makefile - what are the differences?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What are the effects of using `make` vs `$(MAKE)` inside a makefile i.e. submakes?

Are there some [makeflags](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html) that are/are not propagated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing is that if make [sees that the recipe contains the `MAKE` variable reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html), it knows that the recipe is a submake and it will configure the command properly as a submake.  This matters for parallel builds, terminal management, etc.

There are definitely some flags that are not propagated to submakes, but most are.  You've already pointed to the documentation that describes this.

Comment: Plus difference: some systems ships a built-in `make` (the BSD's, for example) which isn't compatible with GNU make. You can install GNU's make and its binary will `gmake`. If the developer use `make` in `Makefile` can cause error.